# Why is "Divide by Zero" or any other exception not raised?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ieee-754

I have a `double[]` on which a LINQ operation is being performed:

```
MD = MD.Select(n => n * 100 / MD.Sum()).ToArray();
```

In some cases, all elements of `MD` are 0 and then `Sum` is also zero. Then `0 * 100 = 0 / 0`, but it is not giving a divide-by-zero exception or any exception. Why is this so?

Comment: Do you have a System.OverflowException?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this:

```
double x = 0.0;
double y = 1.0;
double z = y / x;
```

That won't throw an exception either: it'll leave `z` as positive infinity. There's nothing LINQ-specific here - it's just IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic behaviour.

In your case, you're dividing zero by zero, so you end up with not-a-number.

Comment: agreed z has Positive Infinity. But it should raise exception when converting .ToArray() but after MD = MD.Select(n => n * 100 / MD.Sum()).ToArray(); MD has all elements as zero

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: Why would it raise an exception? In this case you'll get "not a number" instead of infinity as you're dividing 0 by 0, so you'll end up with an array of not-a-number values.

Comment: That is also OK. I'll explain it with a case. Lets say my MD before operation is {0,0}. After MD.Select operation MD still remains the same however it should have been {NaN,NaN}. Why So? If i do don't use LINQ operation and perform it through for loop it populates MD as {NaN,NaN}.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: Hard to say at the moment - please provide a short but complete program demonstrating that. My guess is that you'll find the problem while you prepare the program. (Are you sure you're *actually* assigning back to `MD` for example?)

Comment: You can check for Nan with [`Double.IsNaN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan.aspx).  (Note that NaN != NaN).

Answer (score 5):

IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main() {
            var MD = new double [] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
            var result = MD.Select(n => n*100/MD.Sum()).ToArray();
            foreach (var item in result) {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `Sum` zero because `MD` contains no elements? In this case, the lambda expression isn't executed.

Comment: I just edited my question to explain my answer to your question. MD is initalized with all zero values.